Automating OpenModelica Simulations using OpenModelica Script
I am trying to automate my openModelica simulations. My three goals are as follows:

Run a for loop to run the different simulations
Change the different parameters needed for each simulation with each parameter is described an array
Save the output of the siumlation as a csv file, but with only a few parameters selected (Filesize would be too large if all parameters were selected)

This is the current OMS I have:
loadFile("scenario_1_fists_paper_microgrid_no_bess_no_solar_l2_l3_no_ev_charging.mo"); getErrorString();
parameter Real BESSCapacity[3] = {1620000000, 3240000000, 16200000000}; getErrorString();
parameter String BESSFunction[3] = {"demandResponse", "demandResponse", "peakShaving"}; getErrorString();
equation
  for i in 1:4 loop
    Buildings.Electrical.AC.ThreePhasesBalanced.Storage.Battery BESS(EMax = BESSCapacity[i], SOC_start = 0.5, pf = 0.9) annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {-10, -68}, extent = {{10, -10}, {-10, 10}}, rotation = 90)));
    Buildings.Utilities.IO.Python_3_8.Real_Real level_2_ev_charger_random_generator(functionName = BESSFunction[i] ,moduleName = "pythonFile",nDblRea = 1, nDblWri = 1, samplePeriod = 900)  annotation(
    Placement(visible = true, transformation(origin = {89, -51}, extent = {{9, -9}, {-9, 9}}, rotation = 0)));
    simulate(conf_paper_microgrid, fileNamePrefix = "run_1", outputFormat = "csv"); getErrorString();
  end for;


I am not sure if for loops in openmodelica script are the same as in openmodelica. Also, how to I save the simulation's csv file with only select parameters from the simualtion (building_load.P, BESS.P, etc.)  I am new to openmodelica scripting, so apologies if some of these questions are trivial. Thank you for the help.
Edit suggested from comments:
loadFile("scenario_1_fists_paper_microgrid_no_bess_no_solar_l2_l3_no_ev_charging.mo"); getErrorString();
parameter Real BESSCapacity[3] = {1620000000, 3240000000, 16200000000}; getErrorString();
parameter String BESSFunction[3] = {"demandResponse", "demandResponse", "peakShaving"}; getErrorString();
equation
  for i in {1, 2, 3} loop
    \\ Do something for parameter sweep
    simulate(conf_paper_microgrid, fileNamePrefix = "run_1", outputFormat = "csv"); getErrorString();
  end for;



You cannot do it like that but is possible, see https://openmodelica.org/forum/default-topic/1670-how-to-perform-a-parameter-sweep.html

To filter see simulate and variableFilter: https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.simulate.html.

Only these function calls can be done in scripting: https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.html

I understand the viable filter, but I have a couple of questions about the for loop.

@AdrianPop. I am a little confused about the parameter sweep after reading the fourm link you sent me. I only see it use overide for a modelica parameter, not a library parameter like the one I am using. Any idea how I can do a parameter sweep with the library parameters? Thanks.

I will try to give you an example later today.

This can be done in two ways, using loadString or setComponentModifierValue:
loadFile("scenario_1_fists_paper_microgrid_no_bess_no_solar_l2_l3_no_ev_charging.mo"); getErrorString();

BESSCapacity := {1620000000, 3240000000, 16200000000}; getErrorString();
BESSFunction := {"demandResponse", "demandResponse", "peakShaving"}; getErrorString();


// using loadString to build a model on the fly
loadFile("scenario_1_fists_paper_microgrid_no_bess_no_solar_l2_l3_no_ev_charging.mo"); getErrorString();
for i in 1:4 loop
  loadString(
"model conf_paper_microgrid_" + String(i) + "
   extends conf_paper_microgrid(
     BESS(EMax = " + String(BESSCapacity[i]) + ", SOC_start = 0.5, pf = 0.9),
     level_2_ev_charger_random_generator(functionName = " + BESSFunction[i] + ", moduleName = \"pythonFile\", nDblRea = 1, nDblWri = 1, samplePeriod = 900));
end conf_paper_microgrid_" + String(i) + ";"); getErrorString();
 simulate(stringTypeName("conf_paper_microgrid" + String(i)), fileNamePrefix = "run_" + String(i), outputFormat = "csv"); getErrorString();
end for;


/* second approach, use setComponentModifierValue, not sure if it works
for i in 1:4 loop
  setComponentModifierValue(conf_paper_microgrid, BESS, $Code((EMax = BESSCapacity[i], SOC_start = 0.5, pf = 0.9))); getErrorString();
  setComponentModifierValue(conf_paper_microgrid, level_2_ev_charger_random_generator, $Code((functionName = BESSFunction[i], moduleName = "pythonFile", nDblRea = 1, nDblWri = 1, samplePeriod = 900));
  simulate(conf_paper_microgrid, fileNamePrefix = "run_" + String(i), outputFormat = "csv"); getErrorString();
end for;
*/


Is functionName is a string or a reference? If is a string then you would need to add quotes: functionName = " + BESSFunction[i] + " -> functionName = "" + BESSFunction[i] + "" ...

Apologies for the delay. I needed to fix some other part of the simulation, The Function name refers to a python script within the Modelica buildings library. However, it looks for the reference as a string if that makes sense.

I ran it with both version of the code. It runs, and outputs no error, but it does not implement the simulation.

Output: $ omc run_parameter_sweep.mos
true
"Notification: Automatically loaded package Modelica 4.0.0 due to uses annotation from conf_paper_microgrid.
Notification: Automatically loaded package Complex 4.0.0 due to uses annotation from Modelica.
Notification: Automatically loaded package ModelicaServices 4.0.0 due to uses annotation from Modelica.
Notification: Automatically loaded package Buildings 9.1.0 due to uses annotation from conf_paper_microgrid.
"
{1620000000,3240000000,16200000000}
""
{"return_zero","peak_shaving_triple_zero","peak_shaving_triple_zero"}
""

Is quite complicated to help out if we don't know more details. Would it be possible to send us the script and the model to OpenModelica@ida.liu.se so we can debug the issue?

Sure, I will send it to you. Thanks
