Change parameter values of nested model in OMShell
i am trying to get familiar with OMShell because i need to do multiple simulations with models in my self-written package extending models of the buildings library...multiple runs, where i want to vary weatherfiles used and some values within a parameter-record defining my model. I'd like to write a script (.mos) to automate this process and came across the command "setParameterValue()". Trying to use it to manipulate a parameter of a model within the model i simulate doesn*t seem to work as i get an Error-message stating that it couldn't find the class. But it works when i want to manipulate a parameter in the model i want to simulate itself.
I loaded my package >>loadFile(/home/.../mypackage.mo") and simulated the model >>simulate(mypackage.mymodel). After that i tried to change one parameter of a model inside the simulated model >>setParameterValue(mypackage.mymodel.anothermodelinsidemymodel, parameter_to_change, value).
As long as the parameter is in the model i simulate itsef, it works. But going one model-level deeper i cant change any parameter.
Is there a restriction for this command to only be applicable on the model that i simulate and not on ones within it? I would like to know how to access the parameters that are on a "deeper level"....hope you get what i want to express. Thank you very much for your help in advance!
Roman

See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78376146/automating-openmodelica-simulations-using-openmodelica-script

Hi Adrian, thank you for your reply! Please check the (my) new answer to my question below, since the reply would be too long here!

i tried the second solution in the link in your reply
loadFile("/home/roman/Modelica/BUI_MyLib/BUI_MyLib.mo") // loading my library
simulate(BUI_MyLib.Scenarios.Examples.BenchmarkTR, startTime=0, stopTime=1) // "BenchmarkTR" is the class containing the class "weaDat" where i want to change the parameter defining the altitude in my weather model
plot(weaDat.alt) // "alt" is set to 201 by default
setComponentModifierValue(BUI_MyLib.Scenarios.Examples.BenchmarkTR.weaDat, alt, 1)
simulate(BUI_MyLib.Scenarios.Examples.BenchmarkTR, startTime=0, stopTime=1)
plot(weaDat.alt) // value of "alt" is still at 201
I don't get any response when executing the setComponentenModifierValue() command...no "Error:" and no "OK"
getComponentModifierValue(BUI_MyLib.Scenarios.Examples.BenchmarkTR.weaDat, alt) seems to work and returns "" since no modifier is set
Is the "loadString"-method you also mentioned the only way to change a parameter like i want to do? I am having difficulties to understand what the whole thing should look like to suite my application.
Thank you very much!
Roman

Should be something like that if I understand your class correctly:
setComponentModifierValue(BUI_MyLib.Scenarios.Examples.BenchmarkTR, weaDat, $Code(alt=1))

Dear Adrian, thank you very much! Took me a while to get familiar with this command, since the information i found here (https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.setElementModifierValue.html) is quite sparse...at least for me. What works for me is:
setComponentModifierValue(BUI_MyLib.Scenarios.Examples.BenchmarkTR, weaDat.alt, $Code(=1))
Is there more to read about that "$Code(=...)" part? It's new to me, not mentioned in the documentation i linked and i would like to understand it. Why can't i use a simple number?

Because the submodifier can be more than an single number and you need a code quoting mecanism that's why we have $Code, one can use it like: $Code(a(x=1, y=2) = 15) to set a submodifier and a binding to a component.

OK, thanks! I understand that everything written in the parentheses of the $Code-part will be directly taken as the modifier 'value'. Is there a also a special way to fill in the value of a parameter that i defined in my script calling the modifierValue-function? This way it would rather write the parameters name than its actual value.
