Setting model reference dynamically in OMShell
I wan't to set up a for loop in OMShell, where i call different models according to the iteration variable of the loop (e.g. 'i'). To me it looks like i have to find a way to construct the model reference (e.g. mylibrary.mymodel) as a string and convert it (if possible) from String to a reference.
I was thinking of sth like:
loadFile("/home/Modelica/mylibrary.mo");
model_String := "path.to.model.in.mylibraray." + "model"; //the name of "model" is changed throughout the process of the script in a for loop, later
model_reference := (some process of converting the string in 'model_String' to a real reference);
simulate(model_reference, stopTime=1, outputFormat="mat");
Is this possible resp. is it possible to dynamically simulate different models in OMShell?
Thank you very much!
Roman
----------Solution-----------
In case anybody want's to do the same and is searching for an example, here is what worked for me....except the part with simVar - i still don't manage to write the variables in the right format (maybe someone knows). Kudos to adrian for the quick help!
loadFile("/path/to/my/library/mylibrary.mo");
lst := {"SimRun1", "SimRun2", "SimRun3"};
for run in lst loop
dir := "/path/to/save/the/results/"+run;
mkdir(dir);
cd(dir);
ref := stringTypeName("mylibraray.model" + run); //model+run=actual name of class in my case
simVar := {"weaDat.AirPressure", "weaDat.AirTemp", "weaDat.CloudCover", "weaDat.RelHumidity", "weaDat.WaterInAir", "weaDat.WindDirection", "weaDat.WindSpeed", "weaDat.SkyRadiation", "weaDat.TerrestrialRadiation", "weaDat.add.u1", "weaDat.add.u2", "ZweiPersonenBuero.TAir", "ZweiPersonenBuero.TRad", "dataOut.H_gWin[1]"};
simulate(ref, stopTime=3.1536e7, numberOfIntervals=8760, fileNamePrefix=run, outputFormat = "csv", variableFilter = simVar);
end for;


stringTypeName: https://build.openmodelica.org/Documentation/OpenModelica.Scripting.stringTypeName.html

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78376146/automating-openmodelica-simulations-using-openmodelica-script
